# Sending HTTP Requests in Swift

Tags: http, swift

I have tried all the methods I came across on Google but none work. So my question is how would I get the contents of a web page using Swift? Like send an HTTP Request to a website and get the source of the page.

Any help or references welcome :D.

I have tried Alamofire and a bunch of other projects on Github as well.

Comment: Do you just need the html source code of the webpage (in text form)?

Comment: @JoJoe yes that is all I need. Sort of like how PHP does it with file_get_contents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will get you the source code of a website in text form:

```
let source = NSString(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com"), encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding, error: nil)
```

Edit: If the website contains non-ascii characters, you can of course use 'NSUTF8StringEncoding'. If you don't want to block the main thread you should of course use an async_dispatch call.

Comment: I've been looking for that hours and hours on end.

Comment: This code will not work (or produce strange results) if there are non-ASCII characters on the page. Also, this method will block the main thread. If you just want to get the source code once or twice for debug purposes, fair enough, but it's not the sort of thing you should build your app around. It's completely inadequate for anything beyond a simple HTTP GET.

Comment: Yes, and that's fair enough, and I'm not in favor of using the most involved solution. But the question said "sending HTTP requests". Initing an NSString from a URL doesn't cover very many of all possible HTTP requests. Chances are you'll have to do a POST too in the same program.

Comment: Sure, I admit, if you want to do anything more serious, this might not suffice. It is simply a quick and easy solution for the question "how would I get the contents of a web page using Swift?"

Answer (score 0):

How about `NSURLConnection` and `NSURLRequest`?

`sendAsynchronousRequest:...` passes an `NSData` object into the completion handler alongside the NSURLRequest. `sendSynchronousRequest:...` (please avoid) returns an `NSData` object. Starting a request with start requires you to have hooked up a delegate to that request that implements `NSURLConnectionDelegate` where various methods are called as data comes in or the request fails. I'd recommend `sendAsynchronousRequest:...`.

Comment: After some searching on SOF, I found this that uses NSURLConnection and NSURLRequest. It only returns the headers, I want it to return the full page source. How would I do this? [Code To Do That](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=cy7RB1bk)

Comment: Fair enough - moved the actual answer from a comment to the answer.